# Save and parse CSV file from URL

Tags: ruby, csv

I am looking for an implementation that would allow me to download a CSV file from a browser (via a URL), to a point where I can open that file manually and view its contents in CSV form.

I have been doing some research and can see that I should use the [IO](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.3/IO.html), [CSV](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.0.0/libdoc/csv/rdoc/CSV.html) or [File](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/File.html) classes.

I have a URL that looks something like:

```
"https://mydomain/manage/reporting/index?who=user&users=0&teams=0&datasetName=0&startDate=2015-10-18&endDate=2015-11-17&format=csv"
```

From what I have read I have:

```
href = page.find('#csv-download > a')['href']
csv_path =  "https://mydomain/manage/reporting/index?who=user&users=0&teams=0&datasetName=0&startDate=2015-10-18&endDate=2015-11-17&format=csv"
require 'open-uri'
download = open(csv_path, ssl_verify_mode: OpenSSL::SSL::VERIFY_NONE)
IO.copy_stream(download, 'test.csv')
```

This actually outputs:

```
 2684
```

Which tells me that I have successfully got the data?

When downloading the file, the contents are just

```
#<StringIO:0x00000003e07d30>
```

Would there be any reason for this?

It's where to go from here, could anyone point me in the right direction please?

Comment: IO.copy_stream returns the bytes written and it seems like you successfully saved the file. Both IO and File are valid methods.

Comment: So I just need to read the file now with the CSV class methods available?

Comment: Added a complete example as an answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should read from remote, write and then parse the file:

```
require 'open-uri'
require 'csv'
url =  "https://mydomain/manage/reporting/index?who=user&users=0&teams=0&datasetName=0&startDate=2015-10-18&endDate=2015-11-17&format=csv"

download = open(url)
IO.copy_stream(download, 'test.csv')
CSV.new(download).each do |l|
   puts l
end
```

Comment: thanks for your help so far, I have updated my question and was wondering if you could take a look please

Comment: `open(url)` returns a `StringIO` object. To see it's content you have to use `download.read`. I suggest to read the `IO` documentation

Comment: This is way too cumbersome.

Comment: But it covers the csv part of the question which your example is lacking. Still I like your examples.

Answer (score 0):

If all you want to do is read a file and save it, it's simple. This untested code should be all that's required:

```
require 'open-uri'

CSV_PATH = "https://mydomain/manage/reporting/index?who=user&users=0&teams=0&datasetName=0&startDate=2015-10-18&endDate=2015-11-17&format=csv"

IO.copy_stream(
  open(
    CSV_PATH,
    ssl_verify_mode: OpenSSL::SSL::VERIFY_NONE
  ),
  'test.csv'
)
```

OpenURI's `open` returns an IO stream, which is all you need to make `copy_stream` happy.

More typically you'll see the `open`, `read`, `write` pattern. [`open`](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.2.3/libdoc/open-uri/rdoc/Kernel.html) will create the IO stream for the remote document and [`read`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.3/IO.html#method-c-read) will retrieve the remote document and [`write`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.3/IO.html#method-c-write) will output it to a text file on your local disk. See their documentation for more information.

```
require 'open-uri'

CSV_PATH = "https://mydomain/manage/reporting/index?who=user&users=0&teams=0&datasetName=0&startDate=2015-10-18&endDate=2015-11-17&format=csv"

File.write(
  'test.csv',
  open(
    CSV_PATH,
    ssl_verify_mode: OpenSSL::SSL::VERIFY_NONE
  ).read
)
```

There might be a scalability advantage to using `copy_stream` for huge files that potentially wouldn't fit into memory. That'd be a test for the user.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a one-liner I use. Of course if the file is huge - I might want to stream or download it first, but this works in 99% of cases, just fine.

```
require 'open-uri'
require 'csv'

csv_data = CSV.readlines(open(download_url), headers: true)
```